# What are the consequences of declaring a SQL Server Variable with two (or more) '@' symbols?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables

Ordinarily, I would declare a variable

```
declare @ConType int;
```

Or something akin to this.

Recently in a code review I encountered a decalration using a double '@' (like the built in @@rowcount, for example), i.e.

```
declare @@ConType int;
```

I notice that one can stupulate any (reasonable) number of '@':

```
declare @@@@ConType int;
```

And the variable should function ok. So, the following should work:

```
declare @@@@ConType int;
set @@@@ConType = 1;
select @@@@ConType;
```

Obvoiusly, the above is a little stupid, but my question is really whether there is any significance in declaring variables in this way? Are there any side-effects? Should we avoid doing so?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first character of a variable name has to be an at sign ('@'). Any at signs after that do not have any particular significance and are treated just like any other character.

*However*, you should avoid declaring variables that begin with a double at sign ('@@') because, in the words of [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx):

> Some Transact-SQL functions have names that start with double at signs (@@). To avoid confusion with these functions, you should not use names that start with @@.

Of course, this means that variable names beginning with three or more at signs should also not be used.

I guess it's not exactly wrong to use at signs later in the variable name if the second character is not an at sign, but it just looks confusing, so it's probably not a good idea either.

Comment: Has this advice changed? I have found the convention being broken in an example provided in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-logevent-transact-sql

Answer (score 4):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953.aspx):

> The names of some Transact-SQL system functions begin with two at signs (@@). Although in earlier versions of Microsoft SQL Server, the @@functions are referred to as global variables, they are not variables and do not have the same behaviors as variables. The @@functions are system functions, and their syntax usage follows the rules for functions.

[EDIT] To clarify, SQL Server will let you put however many at signs you want at the front of your variable names, but technically @@ objects are not variables at all. They behave like that though they look like system functions. Some people try to use the @@ to designate a global variable, but that doesn't work; there is no way for you to create a global variable. This behavior is typically just left over from using earlier versions of SQL Server.

Comment: So, even though I can do `set @@ConType = 1`, the variable `@@ConType` is actually a system function? Doesn't sound quite right to me. Also, what about `@@@ConType`, `@@@@ConType`, etc etc?

Comment: @James: `@@ConType` isn't a system function (and doesn't magically become one just because it has a double at sign), but it *looks* as if it might be one, and that's confusing.

Comment: My bad - I edited the answer to say that @@ConType *looks* like a system function, even though it's not. @@functions that are system functions refers to actual system functions, of course. You can stick however many @ sings you want in front of a variable name and it makes no difference to SQL Server. Typically when you see two at signs, though, it's a remnant of the older, out-of-date SQL Server behavior.

Comment: Just come across a MS function that use `@@` to denote `OUTPUT` variables, nice to see they follow [their own advice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874(v=sql.100).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm concerned there is nothing overly wrong with it as long as your not colliding with a system function, however just because `@@` is a valid variable name doesn't mean you should use it.

Chances are if your declaring variables `@var`, `@@var` and `@@@var` then your variables are badly named and its going to cause confusion to those who have to maintain it in the future.

Edit -

For further reading on the subject of just how much you can abuse sql while keeping it valid see this wonderful post by Phil Factor - [Evil Code](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/philfactor/archive/2009/08/14/evil-code.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

It looks silly, and Microsoft recommends against it in the [rules for identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx), ("Some Transact-SQL functions have names that start with double at signs (@@). To avoid confusion with these functions, you should not use names that start with @@."), but otherwise the examples you've given comply with those same rules and are perfectly valid.

There should be no harm in using variables of this form, although there's probably no legitimate reason for doing it either.